# Bridge Movie Night - Halloween Special

Tags: discussion, community-event

While I had originally planned to move Movie Night to a bimonthly schedule (and thus we'd skip October since we had a Movie Night last month), I couldn't ignore the lure of a Halloween-themed Movie Night. And moving to a bimonthly schedule afterwards would mean the next Movie Night would be in December (another holiday special!). So with that said, let's shoot for a late October showing and suggest your favorite Halloween-themed movies (although they don't *have* to be Halloween-themed).

<strike>[Movie Night Scheduling Poll](http://strawpoll.me/5656872) (ends October 10)</strike>

Now I know that the timing for Movie Night is not very optimal for everyone. In our initial showings, we started on a Friday so I had to schedule for 11:00 PM UTC-0 just to be able to start the showing. Now that we've moved to a weekend schedule, I think it's time to rethink when in the day the showings should start.

Well, the votes are in and our next movie night will take place on the Halloween weekend. I've set up a Doodle poll to establish a good time for the upcoming (and all future) movie nights. [The poll is here](http://doodle.com/poll/bf8mnpc29a82r54v) and the times *should* be adjusted for your timezone. The first time slot is 5:00 PM UTC-0.

Answer (score 7):

## Movie Suggestion: The Nightmare Before Christmas

[image: Nightmare Before Christmas poster]

A classic Halloween movie directed by Tim Burton, this follows the story of Jack Skellington, the Pumpkin King. Jack, as part of his services to "Halloween Town" helps organize Halloween every year, but has found lately he is a bit bored with the tired routine. So Jack, in all his wisdom, ventures out to find new opportunities to make Halloween even better, and stumbles across another holiday town: Christmas!

The Nightmare Before Christmas was a critical, box office and cult hit. The movie is stop-motion movie like some of Tim Burton's later films, and also has a lot of Burton's usual flair.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qrB9I3DM80) | [Rotten Tomatoes (94%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/nightmare_before_christmas/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107688/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: Oh yes, this is good.

Answer (score 2):

## Movie Suggestion: The Halloween Tree

[image: The Halloween Tree]

Based on the Ray Bradbury novel [of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Halloween_Tree), and narrated by him as well, The Halloween Tree is a Halloween film about a kid who steals a pumpkin, and then gets magicked across the world. His friends follow him around the world trying to track him down, and adventures abound.

I haven't seen this film since I was a kid, but I remember it being the bees knees, and it appears to have won a few rewards as well, so it's probably not just nostalgia talking. So sure, we *could* watch The Nightmare Before Christmas, but I'm sure you've all seen that one before, but I bet most of you haven't even heard of The Halloween Tree...so let's all go on an adventure together.

[Trailer](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the-halloween-tree/trailers/11199280/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (8.4 user score)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0191173/) | [Preview Clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mInv6t35GM4)